# How do I define a new virtual machine in QEMU?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, virtual-machine, fedora, qemu

I have installed `QEMU` for fedora via:

```
yum install qemu
```

Now how do I start it ? I mean how do I define a new virtual machine, like I do in `VMware`? Also I don't see any icon made for `QEMU`.

Comment: Did you try running the `qemu` command (in some terminal)? Did you read the output of `man qemu`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yeah. Isn't there any graphical interface like VMware ? I see only the terminal that looks for the boot image

Comment: Most Linux programs have a command line interface.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create a virtual disk

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 disk01.img 10G
```

After that you can start your virtual system

```
qemu -hda disk01.img -m 256
```

Comment: aah..can you please explain these attributes ? `-f qcow2 disk01.img 10G`

Comment: -f qcow2 = define a new file/virtual hard disk with qcow2 format and the size of 10GB (you can find more information about qcow at wikipedia -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qcow)